# Is it possible to make iOS to detect custom gesture/motion at background?

Tags: ios, gesture-recognition, motion

iOS does provide with function that is used for its shake motion detect.

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event ;
```

But I have custom gestures instead, such as WAVE, etc. I tried to use the motionBegan, but the results looks really bad. AKA, you need to shake your phone first to trigger this function. I was wondering, is there better solution on this,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Core Motion framework to detect how the device is being oriented / accelerated. For a custom gesture, you will have to write code that figures out whether what is happening is your gesture. This is not at all easy to do. I give a very simple, rather artificial example here, where I detect (with some latency) that the phone is being slapped sideways into the user's open palm: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch35.html#_raw_acceleration